# ggplot double linechart and 3 columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, rfacebook

I've extracted by Rfacebook package some data about Facebook Pages. What I'm trying to get is two linecharts side by side like the attached image (a linechart for each UserName) where I can display likes, comments and shares at the same time like the attached image.

```
FromUser  time      shares  comments    likes
User 1    17-01-18  67      5           100
User 2    16-01-18  46      13          65
User 1    16-01-18  32      25          32
User 1    15-01-18  45      36          45
User 2    14-01-18  64      52          58
```

I tried with the following code but i doesn't work. Any suggestion?

```
line_chart <- ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = time)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = shares), colour="blue") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = comments), colour = "grey") +
  geom_line(aes(y = likes), colour = "grey") +  
  ylab(label="Number of interactions") + 
  xlab("Days")
```

[image: linechart]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current plot might be easier to create by rearranging your data a bit with `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
#use gather to make a metric column
dataframe.2 <- dataframe %>% gather(Metric, Value, -time, -FromUser)

#convert date for easy ploting
dataframe.2$time <- as.Date(dataframe.2$time , format = "%d-%m-%y")
```

Which gives one record per user, time, and metric:

```
FromUser       time   Metric Value
User 1 2018-01-17   shares    67
User 2 2018-01-16   shares    46
User 1 2018-01-16   shares    32
User 1 2018-01-15   shares    45
User 2 2018-01-14   shares    64
User 1 2018-01-17 comments     5
User 2 2018-01-16 comments    13
User 1 2018-01-16 comments    25
User 1 2018-01-15 comments    36
User 2 2018-01-14 comments    52
User 1 2018-01-17    likes   100
User 2 2018-01-16    likes    65
User 1 2018-01-16    likes    32
User 1 2018-01-15    likes    45
User 2 2018-01-14    likes    58
```

Now feed into ggplot:

```
ggplot(data = dataframe.2, aes(x = time, y = Value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = Metric, group = Metric)) +facet_wrap(~FromUser) + 
  xlab("Date") + ylab("Number of interactions")
```

Final Plot:
[image]